# Using a library in C code

Tags: c, fftw

I've recently downloaded the FFTW3 'library' which comes as a .zip with various files from .dll, .exe, .def and to .h.

All I'd like to do is be able to call a function from this library to use in my C code.

Could someone explain the steps for me in simple terms?

I'm using Bloodshed Dev-C++ compiler and currently downloading Visual Studio

Thanks.

Comment: The FFTW3 tutorial shows how to include the header - the rest depends on your build environment (possibly make? possibly generated by the IDE?). You're looking for some way to tell it where to find your new .h file(s), and that it should link your new .dll file(s).

Answer (score 0):

`#include "absolute or relative path to library"`

when importing user defined .h files use quotation marks instead of `< >`.

You can specify the absolute or relative path if the file lives outside the current directory that your main program lives.

Comment: What do I need to do to all the files? compile them with something or move them somewhere?